# Being+Adjective/Noun

Tags: grammar

I am having a problem whether to use adjective or noun after the word "being". Can I use both after "being". For example:

1. You're being perverted.

= You are being a pervert.

2. You're being ignorant.

= You're being an ignoramus.

Comment: It's pretty much the same as with "is" -- "He is ignorant" vs "He is an ignoramus".  The choice is up to you.

Comment: @HotLicks Surely *ignoramus* can only be used in the first-person plural not the third-person singular. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences are small and may not matter in most circumstances.

I note that *You're being perverted* is ambiguous: it could mean someone is perverting you or - as I will assume here - that *You are acting in the manner of a perverted person*. This is a little different from *You are being a pervert*, which says that you are not only acting in the manner of a perverted person but that you are such a person, at least for now.

Similarly, *You're being ignorant* describes your state of mind in respect of something you don't know or don't understand. This is not the same as *you are being an ignoramus*, which suggests that you not only act ignorantly but that you really are an ignoramus, at least for now.

Comment: I disagree; “is” asserts identity while “is being” asserts current state, regardless of whether followed by  noun or adjective.

Comment: I left my answer in a hurry. You point out what I should have added. Now edited. I have marked you up. Thanks.